# Problems with MongoDB, PHP and Serialisation

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, php-mongodb

Im looking to see if anyone can shed some light on a problem im having.

In my collection Y, I have a field called ADJU, which has stored in it, the serialised PHP array of MongoIDs.

One example field is 
    "a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:4:\"MBID\";C:7:\"MongoId\":24:{4f2c5b9bb9a21d5010000005}}}"

The parameter im passing in is 
    "4f2c5b9bb9a21d5010000005"

```
public function read_adjudicating(MongoID $account_identifier){
    $regexObj = new MongoRegex("/".$account_identifier->__toString()."/");
    var_dump($regexObj);
    $result = $this->connection->X->Y->find(array('ADJU' => $regexObj), array('__id'));
    var_dump($result);
```

Can anyone work out why it is giving me 0 records, when as you can see, one example definately has it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: On a side note, there are no php errors or anything and my suspicions are on the use of "s

Comment: why would you ever store a serialized string in a nosql datastore?

Comment: Part proof-of-concept, and the data came from MySQL on a previous install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not the query:

```
db.illogical.insert({'ADJU': "a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:4:\"MBID\";C:7:\"MongoId\":24:{4f2c5b9bb9a21d5010000005}}}"})
db.illogical.find({'ADJU': /4f2c5b9bb9a21d5010000005/})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f605b9e5d2b96c06d2adb27"), "ADJU" : "a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:4:\"MBID\";C:7:\"MongoId\":24:{4f2c5b9bb9a21d5010000005}}}" }
```

Which means the php code you've written doesn't correspond to the query you expect, or the data isn't in the format you expect.

Rather than investigate why though - you'd be better off IMO either updating the script you used to import the data from mysql to deserialize before inserting to mongo - or write a (php) script to read the already-serialized-in-mongo data, deserialize it - and save it again.

Comment: Turns out, I was using var_dump to debug, which doesnt work with an iterator (MongoCollection). When i ran iterator_to_array before it, it worked fine. Thanks for the tips though, its much appreciated!